# Highcharts - Add bar graph to a pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

The goal is to try and show a breakdown of a pie chart by displaying bar graphs off of each slice. This way the user can see the sub-values of each slice in a "different way".

Any idea how to add the bars?

[image: pie _with_bars]

**EDIT:**

Here is a current iteration. The larger the value, the smaller the "innerSize" value for the outer ring.

[image: using inner size]

Comment: It's not possible to combine bar charts with a pie, however you can do something similar which would give you the desired result. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut

Comment: or you can just use drilldown which is much neater!

Comment: Agree on the drill down, but the bosses are really pushing for the bars. So far, looks like only option is to use the Renderer to dynamicly create the bars and use transforms to put them in place. Hoping for something simpler.

Comment: Any other ways to get this effect?

Comment: This might be one of the most terrible ways to try to view data that I've seen. I don't know of a good way to achieve the effect, but would highly recommend not visualizing data in this manner even if you find one.

Comment: agreed that looks so odd - when working with data viz, its much less about what you think is cool and more about actually showing the story of the data, this is just gonna throw people off.

Comment: Agreed. This is the requirement from the bosses. Think we have a possible solution though... Make the "bars" by creating pie chart rings of various radii. Once done will post code/screenshots here.

Comment: This was pointed out before, but should say that again - this is not looking good. To get exactly this chart you could use renderer. Pie chart slices will not be rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a "wind rose" chart? It's similar in style and function to what your higher-ups are suggesting. See http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-wind-rose in the Highcharts demo page.

[image]